# How to set canvas width / height using parent divs attributes

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have been trying to set a p5.js canvas inside a div, and use the divs width to control the canvas width, within a jekyll post. In the markdown file I am constructing a div that I know sits at the top of the post.

```
<div id="myCanvas"</div>
<script src="/js/p5Sketches/firstP5Sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the javascript I have the p5.js canvas assigned to the div. I have tried to get the parent's div clientWidth but I am getting some really strange outputs.

```
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var width = canvasDiv.clientWidth;

function setup() {
  var sketchCanvas = createCanvas(width,450);
  sketchCanvas.parent("myCanvas");
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed){
    fill(0);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 40, 40);

  if (keyIsPressed == true){
    clear();
  }
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(width,450);
}
```

When I print out the canvasDiv attributes I get the correct clientWidth value (844px), but then print out the width variable and it is 1244px. In the chrome inspector the p5 canvas ends up being width=100px.

```
<canvas id="" width="200" height="900" style="width: 100px !important; height: 450px !important;" class=""></canvas>
```

The value is not passed on to the p5 canvas, and I can't work out why. As an aside I am not using any css to style the myCanvas or canvas elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All I can see is a tiny mistake like this: `<div id="myCanvas"</div>` Tag isn't closed?

Comment: Thanks Adib, I did have the closing > in the code, it was a typo in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to capture the parent elements information within `setup()`

The default width and height for `setup()` is 100x100. And if width isn't defined inside setup(), it'll be overwritten with the default value. From the documentation:

> The system variables width and height are set by the parameters passed
>   to this function. If createCanvas() is not used, the window will be
>   given a default size of 100x100 pixels.

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas

Which I tested and proved in this image:

[image: width and height are pre-defined by setup() already]

The following is the correct code you should replace your setup() function with:

```
function setup() {
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var width = canvasDiv.offsetWidth;
    var sketchCanvas = createCanvas(width,450);
    console.log(sketchCanvas);
    sketchCanvas.parent("myCanvas");
}
```